# Not able to open any web page in browser using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I tried to launch firefox browser and open a web page example `google.com`, using selenium webdriver. I was succesfully able to launch the browser but there was some issue with launching web page. I got error as

> Exception in thread "main"
>
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not
>   start a new session.
>
> Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser
>   start-up failure.

My same code works well in other systems.

```java
package beast;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class launchGmail {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("1");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        System.out.println("2");
        driver.get("http://google.com");
        System.out.println("3");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is version of your firefox browser?

Comment: Make sure your FF version is current and get the most recent version of Selenium and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of the incompatibility of the Firefox browser with the version of Selenium you are using. You can either upgrade the version of Selenium WebDriver or Downgrade the Firefox version.